# SQLite Database not showing up in File Explorer

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have an SQLite database in my application. When I go to check if the  database is created or not in File Explorer, there is no any database file within the `data` folder. It didn't even show up using the `adb shell` command. Does this mean that the database hasn't been created yet? Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: you cant see the database if you are testing on a device. If its an emulator then perhaps the databse is not created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using an actual device, you will not be able to see or access it from outside unless you root your phone.

If you are using the emulator, the DDMS view will let you navigate to it and pull it from there.

Or, you could have an issue with creating your DB.  Without seeing your code we cannot tell.

**EDIT**

If you want to get the file off of a real device, you'll need to implement a method to copy it from your data directory to someplace where you do have access (such as your SD card).  This would do the trick:

```
public void backup() {
    try {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File outputFile = new File(sdcard,
                "YourDB.bak");

        if (!outputFile.exists()) 
             outputFile.createNewFile(); 

        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        File inputFile = new File(data, "data/your.package.name/databases/yourDB");
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Error("Copying Failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am using real device Is any way to see database and tables?