# Accessing db file while debugging on real device

Tags: android-sqlite

Is it restricted (security reasons etc.) or something wrong with my dev environment? I can't see inside "data" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11150168/2219600)

If you are using an actual device, you will not be able to see or access it from outside unless you root your phone.

If you are using the emulator, the DDMS view will let you navigate to it and pull it from there.

Or, you could have an issue with creating your DB. Without seeing your code we cannot tell.